# Weird behavior of NSTimer in class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, repeat

I have a real weird behavior of NSTimer object.

I'm trying to call `ChangePic` method with repeat counts of 2 seconds, But the timer isn't repeating. and i have this problem **only in 1 class in the project**

I have 5 View Controllers in my App, and the same code works in all classes except this one.
Does anybody has idea how could it be? is it possible that something blocking the timer ?

-BTW, `ChangePic` Method is called only once, and not repeating.

My Code:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(ChangePic) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[_timer fire];

-(void) ChangePic {
    NSLog(@"testing"); 
}
```

Comment: i totally copy and paste the code in a project an it is working very well. you should search the error other parts of the code i think

Comment: P.S. No need to call `fire`, the timer will start immediately.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the code you posted. Look elsewhere. Is ChangePic() fired once or not at all?

Answer (score 3):

Assign it to the property not the backing variable.

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(ChangePic) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: This has no bearing on the issue. Using ARC, assigning to `_timer` or `self.timer` is the same thing (memory management wise).

Comment: There is no mention of ARC in the question.

Comment: Sure there is. Look at the property declaration. It uses `strong`, not `retain`.

Comment: I agree that it's likely not the issue, but it's still good advice. Perhaps this should be a comment.

Comment: This is irrelevant to this question. You don't need to assign the timer to anything at all unless you're going to use that variable somewhere.

Comment: @Gary Sure it does. `strong` isn't a valid property attribute in MRC, only ARC. If this was MRC then it would be `retain`.

Comment: @rmaddy strong is a synonym for retain in MRC. My answer is probably wrong but it would help if the OP gave some feedback at this point :)

Comment: @Gary Sorry. I stand corrected. I thought `strong` was only valid in ARC. I just created a quick test app using MRC and sure enough, I could use `strong` in a property. Good to know.

Comment: @rmaddy I had to go and check as well!

Comment: Regardless of ARC, the runloop retains scheduled timers.

Comment: Actually guys, i tried them both.. Strong / Retain, and both of them didn't work.. :/

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what your issue is given that there isn't a whole lot of background given. I can tell you that I answered another question where the problem turned out to be the fact that one of the views was blocking the timer. Timers can run on a number of different modes and different scenarios can cause the timer to sometimes be blocked. Try adding the timer to all common modes like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Also, like @Hejazi said, remove the 'fire' method call. It's not needed on a scheduled timer.

Comment: I tried, didnt work aswell.
I also tried to remove all the views from the current ViewController, and it has the same problem.
Btw, when i remove the fire method the >ChangePic< Method didnt get called. and when i added it back, it did.

Comment: Then I agree with @MarcusAdams, the problem must be somewhere else. You could post the code of any spots this view controller is created or used for us to review, or you could just start setting break points and check the value of this view controller and the timer property to make sure they don't get nil'd at any point. There is clearly a problem somewhere else since you mentioned that without the 'fire' method it doesn't get called at all. That should not be the case. The scheduledTimer... method should start the timer automatically. That's a good indicator that something is out of place.